# Trending sort by views and date

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, javascript-objects

I am trying to implement [Hacker News ranking algorithm](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-works-1d9b0cf2c08d) with some custom changes. I need to sort my posts (array of objects) by popularity/trending. Simply, I would like to compare views x publish date and get trending posts.

I have tried this code:

```
const array = [
  { title: "1", views: 100, publishDate: 1 }, // publish date = 1 hour ago
  { title: "2", views: 400, publishDate: 2 }, // publish date = 2 hour ago
  { title: "3", views: 300, publishDate: 3} // publish date = 3 hour ago
];


const sortByTrending = array.sort((a, b) => b.views / Math.pow(b.publishDate, 1.8) - a.views / 
Math.pow(a.publishDate, 1.8));

console.log(sortByTrending);

// Output:
[
  {
    title:"1",
    views:300,
    publishDate:1
  },{
    title:"3",
    views:1000,
    publishDate:3
  },{
    title:"2",
    views:400,
    publishDate:2
  }
];
```

It's working somehow. But is there any better way to achieve more accurate result?

Comment: What are you asking for? A better way to implement your sort function, or a more accurate "trending" algorithm?

Comment: A better way to implement sort function. Thank you :)